# Python erroring when called from Apache but not commandline with close failed in file object destructor:

Tags: php, python, apache, exec

I've a Python script which works perfectly when called from the command-line but dies when called from a php script running on Apache on the same machine.

Error meesage (scraped from Apache error log):

```
close failed in file object destructor:
sys.excepthook is missing
lost sys.stderr
```

Call in PHP:

```
$exec_string = '/usr/bin/python /path/to/file/doSearch.py "' . $data[ 'term' ] . '"' . $id . ' &';
pclose( popen( $exec_string , 'r' ) );
```

The Python file is crunching data and then writing back to the filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing a space after the first argument. Try this:

```
$exec_string = '/usr/bin/python /path/to/file/doSearch.py "' . $data[ 'term' ] . '" ' . $id . ' &';
//      see hat here -->                                                           ^
```

You probably want to make sure you're escaping all that data too, to make it safe for CLI.

Answer (score 0):

There should be some outputs from your process which to be executed in popen function.
However, pclose will cause this exception when do fclose this reading file stream directly.